# React Router - Detect when a user hits the back button which changes the URL's query params

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, back-button, react-router-dom

I have a React component that needs to get data using AJAX (axios) and update the URL's query params when the user clicks a button. Also, more importantly, I want to get the data when user hits the back button, forward button, etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to get data when a user hits the back button or forward button is to do it when the route changes in componentWillReceiveProps, taking advantage of nextProps.

To preface, I am using the 'query-string' package to parse my query string, the 'react-redux' to manage state and get data, and 'react-router-dom' to change routes.

Here's what my componentWillReceiveProps looks like.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

if (this.props.location.search !== nextProps.location.search) {
  let parsed = queryString.parse(nextProps.location.search);
  const search = '?' + queryString.stringify(parsed);
  const uri = ENV_URL + nextProps.location.pathname;
  this.props.getContestEntriesPageData(uri, search);
}
}
```

Here's an example of a function that runs when a user clicks a button which should update the data somwhow.

```
changePage(page_num) {

let parsed = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);

parsed.page = page_num;

const search = '?' + queryString.stringify(parsed);

const routeUri = this.props.location.pathname + search;

this.props.history.push(routeUri);

}
```

I used to include this.props.getContestEntriesPageData(uri, search); in the changePage function, but I found it's best (and necessary) to only have this.props.getContestEntriesPageData(uri, search); in the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle function.

This seems to work okay for me. React Router handles back button changes when going from one page to the next but not when the query params are changed. This is probably what I have to do for each component that changes URL params and not the page if I want the back button to work correctly.